# Get userID and save it in function - Solidity Beginner

Tags: solidity

This is my first **Solidity** project.

I'm trying to create a kind of supply chain, more than anything just practice code.

I came across a problem that I couldn't solve or find the solution online.

Problem: I want to get the user ID and save it in each `function` so it would look like...

```
function Customer() public {
       checked = Process.Received;
       status = Process.NotPaid;
       //userid = Process.< THE ID >
     }
```

I tried with this ...

```
function getStruct() public
     view
     returns (string, uint)
     {
         return (User);

     }
```

But keeps on asking me to have the data located in `memory`. Which I tried but won't work for me.

Full code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract SupplyChain {

  enum Process {
    Unknown,
    Checked,
    Received,
    Paid,
    NotPaid
  }

     Process public status;
     Process public checked;
     Process public userid;


     address user;

     struct User {
       uint  _id;
       string  _firstName;
       string  _lastName;
     }


     constructor() public {
       status = Process.Unknown;
       user = tx.origin;
     }




     function addUser(
       uint256 id,
       string memory _firstName,
       string memory _lastName
     ) public{

     }
// NOT FINISHED NEED TO RETURN USER ID TO PRINT IN TRACKERS.
     function getStruct() public
     view
     returns (string, uint)
     {
         return (User);

     }

     function Factory() public {
       checked = Process.Checked;
       status = Process.NotPaid;
       // print userid
     }
     function TransportOne() public {
       checked = Process.Checked;
       status = Process.NotPaid;
       // print userid
     }
     function Deposit() public {
       checked = Process.Checked;
       status = Process.NotPaid;
       // print userid
     }
     function TransportTwo() public {
       checked = Process.Checked;
       status = Process.NotPaid;
       // print userid
     }
     function Customer() public {
       checked = Process.Received;
       status = Process.NotPaid;
       // print userid
     }

}
```

Comment: Solidity doesn't have a `print` function that would display the value in console. Was your intention to emit an `event`? Or what is your goal with the "print" function - just to debug?

Comment: @PetrHejda my goal is to ``print`` the ``userid``, who checks the status of the product. So the owner could see who did it and have it as a register of each step on the chain. E.G. You write your ``userid`` ``_firstname`` ``_lastname`` and then you say that the product was delivered, then the owner will be able to see that your ``userid`` said that.

Comment: So you want to keep track of the users who call that function? I'm not sure your question is clear as is.

Comment: @PatrickCollins Yes, exactly. As simple as that. Having a function that will return the USERID that used each function E.G ``factory()``. So my desired output would be: Factory, Checked, Paid, ``userid`` and if possible ``_lastName``. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `print` in solidity, you can try to use [events](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/contracts.html#events) for logging.

If you just want to debug, you can try [Remix IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org/#).

Comment: Is not print, that was my bad sorry. It's more like as you receive the output of status and checked I want the output of ``userid`` to be saved in the ``function`` so the owner can see who ``overwrite`` the event ``status`` or ``checked``.